# Why isn't it going to a new line when I clear my input buffer?

Tags: c, function, output, console-application

```
void clrKyb(void) {   
    char input = ' ';
    do {
        scanf("%c", &input);
    } while (input != '\n');
}

void pause(void) {
    //Pause the program as until the user presses enter
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
    clrKyb();
}

int main() {
    struct Item I[21] = {
        { 4.4, 275, 0, 10, 2, "Royal Apples" },
        { 5.99, 386, 0, 20, 4, "Watermelon" },
        { 3.99, 240, 0, 30, 5, "Blueberries" },
        { 10.56, 916, 0, 20, 3, "Seedless Grapes" },
        { 2.5, 385, 0, 5, 2, "Pomegranate" },
        { 0.44, 495, 0, 100, 30, "Banana" },
        { 0.5, 316, 0, 123, 10, "Kiwifruit" },
        { 4.49, 355, 1, 20, 5, "Chicken Alfredo" },
        { 5.49, 846, 1, 3, 5, "Veal Parmigiana" },
        { 5.29, 359, 1, 40, 5, "Beffsteak Pie" },
        { 4.79, 127, 1, 30, 3, "Curry Checken" },
        { 16.99, 238, 1, 10, 2, "Tide Detergent" },
        { 10.49, 324, 1, 40, 5, "Tide Liq. Pods" },
        { 10.99, 491, 1, 50, 5, "Tide Powder Det." },
        { 3.69, 538, 1, 1, 5, "Lays Chips S&V" },
        { 3.29, 649, 1, 15, 5, "Joe Org Chips" },
        { 1.79, 731, 1, 100, 10, "Allen's Apple Juice" },
        { 6.69, 984, 1, 30, 3, "Coke 24 Pack" },
        { 7.29, 350, 1, 50, 5, "Nestea 24 Pack" },
        { 6.49, 835, 1, 20, 2, "7up 24 pack" }
    };
    double val;
    int ival;
    int searchIndex;
    val = totalAfterTax(I[0]);
    printf("totalAfterTax:\n"
           "    yours=%lf\n"
           "program's=44.000000\n", val);
    val = totalAfterTax(I[7]);
    printf("totalAfterTax:\n"
           "    yours=%lf\n"
           "program's=101.474000\n", val);
    ival = isLowQty(I[0]);
    printf("isLowQty:\n"
           "    yours=%d\n"
           "program's=0\n",ival);
    ival = isLowQty(I[14]);
    printf("isLowQty:\n"
           "    yours=%d\n"
           "program's=1\n",ival);
    pause();

    printf("itemEntry, enter the following values:\n");
    printf("        SKU: 999\n"
           "       Name: Red Apples\n"
           "      Price: 4.54\n"
           "   Quantity: 50\n"
           "Minimum Qty: 5\n"
           "   Is Taxed: n\n");
    printf("Enter the values:\n");
    I[20] = itemEntry(999);
    printf("dspItem, Linear:\nYours: ");
    dspItem(I[20], LINEAR);
    printf(" Prog: |999|Red Apples          |    4.54|   No|  50 |   5 |       227.00|\n");
    printf("dspItem, Form:\nYours:\n");
    dspItem(I[20], FORM);
    printf("Programs: \n");
    printf("        SKU: 999\n"
           "       Name: Red Apples\n"
           "      Price: 4.54\n"
           "   Quantity: 50\n"
           "Minimum Qty: 5\n"
           "   Is Taxed: No\n");
    I[20].quantity = 2;
    I[20].isTaxed = 1;
    pause();

    printf("dspItem, Linear with low value and taxed:\nYours: ");

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to execute the last 2 lines in my main, I call the pause function, prompt the user to press enter, and do not progress forward in the program until the user does not press enter. For some reason, when they press enter, the prompt from the pause function and the string from the printf statement are printing on the same line. Isn't it supposed to print on a separate line since pause waits for the user to hit enter? It does it every other time before the last time it runs, but why is it doing it on the last time the function pause is called? Thanks in advance.

Output looks like: `"Press <ENTER> to continue...dspItem, Linear with low value and taxed:"`

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` in your `pause`. `printf` is line buffered by default. So it will not output to the terminal until a newline or an explicit `flush`.

Comment: when asking about a runtime problem, (amongst other things) post code that cleanly compiles.  The posted code does not compile, It is missing function prototypes, it is missing the `#include <stdio.h> statement, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, on your system, `stdout` does not get flushed when input is requested from `stdin`. You can force that with a call to `fflush()`:

```
void pause(void) {
    //Pause the program as until the user presses enter
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...");
    fflush(stdout);
    clrKyb();
}
```

Note that your function `clrKyb()` would run an infinite loop if the end of file is reached in `stdin` before a newline is read.  You should use this instead:

```
void clrKyb(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;  
}
```